# How one can calculate the effect of airplane angle deviation on the final position?

Tags: trigonometry

Consider an airplane was moving along a flight path after `x` seconds it would pass a distance d1 K.M.. If the same  airplane was moving with same speed at some angle from its original flight path, it would also pass the same distance d1 K.M..**The question is how can one calculate the difference between the 2 paths?**
[image: Here is an image for more illustration.]

Comment: This seems more like a maths question than an aviation one. And the two lines labeled d1 in your diagram are not the same length, which is a little confusing.

Comment: is there a way to move to it to stack mathematics?

Comment: I flagged the question for Moderator attention -- they can migrate it.

Comment: how can i move it to stack mathematics (here), without moderator intervention.

Comment: @Ahmed you cannot move without moderator intervention. I moved it 37 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like simple 10th grade geometry.
SOH-CAH-TOA?

Cosine, adjacent, hypotenuse

cosine of the angle = adjacent (red d1)/hypotenuse (blue d1)

Something like that, has been a long time

red d1 will not equal blue d1 unless the angle is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the angle to be $\alpha$ and the distance between them to be $x$. Then,

$\sin(\alpha) = \dfrac{x}{d_1}$

$\implies x= d_1\cdot\sin(\alpha)$

Comment: d1 = AB not AD.

Comment: Yeah but AB =  AC ie the hypotenuse.$\sin = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$

Comment: it is very easy, i wonder why i did not think about it, Thank you